# using cygwin sshd and xwin to launch window application from remote client

Tags: windows-xp, ssh, cygwin, remote-access, x11

Could be a flaming thread but hope you dont mind a question from a curious Joe here.

I have Desktop computer running downstairs running with winxp pro,cygwin,sshd,xwin. 
Whilst that, I am working upstair with my laptop and my wife will be using the desktop downstair(watching movie,etc,etc). My laptop upstairs is already loaded with Mobaxterm (which actually translate to cygwin as well).

I have already configure my desktop properly with user and ssh and xwin. When I use my laptop to ssh into desktop downstairs, starting the xclock, all works fine. I can see the xclock on my laptop.

Here is my question:

1. Is it possible now to run firefox(C:\Program Files\Mozilla\Firefox.exe) on my desktop via ssh and getting the display to laptop, so I could control the desktop downloading from upstairs.
2. After I ssh to my desktop downstair and when I try 
    
   cd \cygdrive\c\Program/ Files\Mozilla 
              ./Firefox

   Nothing came through display on my laptop.

Any advice. I know vnc could work but meaning to say it would interupt my wife work periodically where she is using on the desktop downstair. And, I have already intended to buy another nettop to do this.

Is there any solutions to this for the time being?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work the way you are describing it. You are using SSH + Xwindows to remotely display unix programs like `xclock`, not native Windows apps like firefox. You need to see if you can get Firefox compiled for cygwin on X. I have no idea if it is even possible, you may want to search with keywords "firefox xwindows cygwin".

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do something with Remote Desktop, I'm not sure if it would interrupt your wife's work though. There's a write-up with using it over `ssh` [here](http://blog.revragnarok.com/blog/blog/2008/06/01/19.34).